# How to load test Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I create Azure Mobile Services with .NET Bachand. My service returns the data to client applications(Windows Phone). Data stored in the Azure Sql database. Tell me the best way to test my service. I need to do load testing for my Azure service. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that. If you would like to use Microsoft technologies you can check out the following resources.

[How to load test and get profiling results from a Web API hosted in a Windows Azure Cloud Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/weslbo/archive/2013/10/31/how-to-load-test-and-get-profiling-results-from-a-web-api-hosted-in-a-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx)
[Load Testing with Chuck Sterling](http://www.msn.com/de-de/video/ansehen/episode-145-load-testing-with-chuck-sterling-microsoft-azure-cloud-cover-show/vp-01537c9c-9972-ee1a-d0b8-b0589455cd15)